# JerseyTest with ApacheCXF client does not return a reasonPhrase

Tags: rest, jersey, response, cxf

I have a simple JerseyTest, that looks like this:

```
    final Response getResponse = this.target(endpoint).get();
    assertStatusEquals(Status.NOT_FOUND, getResponse);
    assertEquals("Cannot find something", getResponse.getStatusInfo().getReasonPhrase());
```

This worked fine when using the standard JerseyClient. However, I switched to ApacheCXF because I want to use the PATCH method.

```
...
//We want to support PATCH, which is sucky in Java's HttpUrlConnection.
//That is why we need a different HttpClient implementation (This is ApaceCXF)
//We need to register the JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
private final Client cxfHttpClient = new ClientBuilderImpl().build()
        .register(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);

//Set it before each test

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    this.setClient(this.cxfHttpClient);
}
```

Now this simple test breaks becuase the `.getReasonPhrase()` returns `null`. I haven't changed the server, so I expect the message to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Is seems to be a bug: CXF-8633,

Which is on its way to be fixed: https://github.com/apache/cxf/commit/d23ed9dc87481d9a6cabdb2b6a6e086da6fcce24